# Tags and larger categories in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are so many tags, but are there broader categories in Stack Overflow? e.g. I could imagine php, html, and js being grouped together...

Answer (score -2):

There actually are broader categories, namely the menus you see at the top of the screen: Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, and Unanswered.

Comment: This is totally irrelevant to the question here.